# Use case for responding with 403 status code

Tags: java, http, jakarta-ee, http-status-code-403

I've recently started developing Java EE applications, and I'm trying to understand more about the HTTP status codes, and when they should be used.

One case that I have is when a user logs in and wants to check on the status of an order. The requirement is that a user cannot check on the status of an order that does not belong to them.

The URL for checking an order is, for example:

```
mysite.com/order/status?id=22594
```

The servlet that handles this request will examine the ID parameter, and go off and retrieve the order from the database.

If the user enters the ID of an order that they did not submit, would it be appropriate to return a 403, or respond with an order not found?

Comment: I would forward to proper 403 because it's forbidden for the user to access to this url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your typical situation, I can think of the following use cases:

**Order Id not found**

- Send a **404**. Order does not exist.

**Order Id belongs to someone else.**

- Send a **403** if the user is logged in. (403 means: "I know who you are and you aren't allowed to access this resource)
- Send a **404**. Sometimes it fits to send this status. You wouldn't want to let the end client know if the resource exists. Either the resource exists for this authenticated and authorised user, or it doesn't.

**User is not logged in**

- Send a **401** "Authentication Required" when trying to access the resource.

Answer (score 4):

If the user did not submit the order, or if the order does not belong to the user, then its appropriate to return either of the below response:

1. **404- Resource not found.** This will not reveal to the user if this
   order id exists for another user.
2. **401-Unauthorized.** This will reveal that the order exists, but does not belong to the requesting user.

From security perspective, its better to return **404**.

Answer (score 4):

**from [w3.org](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html):**

> The server understood the request, but is refusing to fulfill it. Authorization will not help and the request SHOULD NOT be repeated. If the request method was not HEAD and the server wishes to make public why the request has not been fulfilled, it SHOULD describe the reason for the refusal in the entity. If the server does not wish to make this information available to the client, the status code 404 (Not Found) can be used instead.

in your case, for security reasons it might be a good idea to show order not found, but in general the answer is 403

Answer (score 3):

I would lean toward returning an `HTTP 404` for an order ID that the user did not submit (missing or not their order). The reasoning here is that the user is authorized to access the `/order/status` page but that the specific order ID was not found.

Returning an `HTTP 403` in the event of an invalid order ID, I feel, sends the wrong message to the user (you are not allowed here).

Whether the order doesn't exists or the order doesn't belong to the authenticated user; the error should be the same or you risk "leaking" information about orders in your system.